# select Query with sum

Tags: sql, database, select, sum

I have a table with 4 columns named `StudentId`,`StudentName`,`SubjectNAme`,`SubjectMark`.

I want write a Query to get a view with two Fields Named `StudentName` and `Total`. The Total is Obtained  by Summing the subject marks of corresponding students.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT StudentName,
       sum(SubjectMark)
FROM   table_name
GROUP  BY StudentId,
          StudentName
```

Comment: I edited this to match exactly what is requested in the question but maybe that was a bit presumptuous. Feel free to roll it back though you should probably explain why it is different from requested.

Comment: @Martin, there is no problem with your editing. I have also added ID field to the selected fields (and hence to the group by fields) because I have learnt through my practice that the actual name might not be unique and therefore grouping by the name might return wrong results. Also OP mentioned this select would be used for a view. I figure such a view is more usable too when it includes the ID field.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax:

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

column_name is the name of coloumn you want to sum

table_name is table name.